# Rasa-x conversation do not have response

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

I have deployed rasa-x on kubernetes, all service seems work fine. Then I have uploaded my model. The model I have tested locally with rasa shell and work fine. After I activate the model and do the conversation, the intent displays right but there has got no response. I have checked the rabbit and postgresql, seems got no exception. Any idea how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem. I did not deploy the action server.